# how gephi count the average path length

Tags: path, gephi

### problem description

I want to know the formula to compute the average path length in the directed graph in Gephi, as the formula in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_path_length) is

> [image: formula.png]

but it seemed the calculate result is different from the gephi, for example,if I have a simple directed graph
[image: figure_1-1.png]
* Node : A,B,C,D
* Edge: (A->B),(B->C),(B->D)
and if I count the average shortest path length by the formula above I will get a result of `0.583` by hand(which is the same as I count by Python NetworkX),but the gephi gave a result of `1.4` which make me comfused
[image: QQ截图20170304152129.jpg]

I search the wiki but it didn't give the formula and the reference for the implement algorithm does not work, so I wonder how gephi count the average path length, is it the same as average shortest path length?

Any help is appreciated, thank you

### Environment

- Version used: Gephi 0.9.1
- Operating System: Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is a bit puzzling I have to say, because it counts in the denominator, all possible vertex pairs. In practice though, not all vertex pairs can produce a valid path.

Gephi has a slightly different logic and counts that number of the actual paths in the denominator. I found it out by looking at the code [here](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/blob/master/modules/StatisticsPlugin/src/main/java/org/gephi/statistics/plugin/GraphDistance.java). What they do is that they count for each node the distance from every other node and *they add all distances together*. They divide this sum with the total number of paths (in your case this is 5). Now the distances for every node are the following:

```
A: 0
B: 1 (reachable only from A)
C: 2 (from A), 1 (from B)
D: 2 (from A), 1 (from B)
```

Now `average path length = (0+1+2+1+2+1)/5 = 1.4`

Answer (score 0):

I used this and got result very close to Gephi

```
path_lengths = [sum(j.values()) for (i,j) in nx.shortest_path_length(g)]
number_of_paths = [len(j.values()) for (i,j) in nx.shortest_path_length(g)]
result=sum(path_lengths)/sum(number_of_paths)
```